# Cómo hago set, clear y toggle de un solo bit?

Tags: c

Tengo una variable la cual quiero poder hacer **set** de un bit en una posición dada. Qué operaciones puedo hacer en el lenguaje C para lograrlo

Answer (score 2):

**SET**

Para hacer **set** (poner en 1, prender un bit), se puede usar la operación de bits **OR** (`|`) junto con la máscara que contenga el bit deseado para establecer en 1.

De esta forma:

```
unsigned int miVariable = 0xF0;
```

Si queremos poner el **bit 1** en **'1'**, de modo que obtendamos el valor final de `0xF2`, podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
miVariable = 0xF0 | 0x02;
```

De modo que el valor final de `miVariable` será de `0xF2`. Visto en binario, pasamos de `0b11110000` a `0b11110010` (la representación mostrada de binario no está soportada por C99).

Un truco muy recurrido es el de crear la máscara a partir de hacer un corrimiento a la izquierda de una constante de '1', de la siguiente forma:

```
miVariable |= 1UL << x;
```

En donde `x` contiene la posición del bit a hacer **set**

**CLEAR**

Para este caso utilizaremos la operación de bits **AND** (`&`) en conjunto con la operación **NOT** (`~`)(complemento a 1s)

```
miVariable &= ~(1UL << x);
```

Tomando el ejemplo anterior, si queremos ahora poner en `0` el **bit 1** (partiendo de que `miVariable`contiene el valor de `0xF2`), entonces el valor de `x` deberá ser `1`. Esto crea la máscara `0b00000010`. Después la operación **NOT** invertirá dicha máscara (`0b11111101`). Haciendo después la operación **AND** obtendremos el valor esperado:

```
 miVariable == 0xF0
```

**TOGGLE**

Para este caso podemos usar la operación de bits **XOR** (`^`)

```
miVariable ^= 1UL << x;
```